# How to show different options for a dependent field

Tags: nodes, dependency-injection

I've 2 options for a dependent field, I would like to show only one option from the dependent field, when the dependees field has a particular value.
Dependees is a radio button. If the value is 'hotel', I have to show the options room and restaurant from the dependant field. Other wise only show restaurant.

Is it possible through manage dependencies of the content type?